# Finding Duplicate names sql

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
SELECT COUNT(organization.ID) 
FROM organization 
WHERE name in ( SELECT name FROM organization GROUP BY name HAVING count( name ) >1 )
AND organization.APPROVED=0 
AND organization.CREATED_AT>'2010-07-30 10:30:21'
```

I'm trying to find duplicates, but this query is taking a very long time roughly 5-6 seconds. Is there another way I can find duplicates without using my method? Thanks.

**SubQuery: 0.28 seconds. Everything 5.98 seconds.**

Comment: I you execute the subquery alone, does it takes long time too? `SELECT name FROM organization GROUP BY name HAVING count( name ) >1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT organization.name, COUNT(organization.ID)
  FROM organization
 WHERE organization.APPROVED=0
   AND organization.CREATED_AT>'2010-07-30 10:30:21'
 GROUP BY name
HAVING count(organization.id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the query in the `WHERE` clause. You can use a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause to accomplish this:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.ID) 
FROM organization o
WHERE o.APPROVED=0 
   AND o.CREATED_AT>'2010-07-30 10:30:21'
GROUP BY o.Name
HAVING COUNT(o.name) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it like:

```
SELECT COUNT(organization.ID)
FROM organization 
WHERE organization.APPROVED=0 
AND organization.CREATED_AT>'2010-07-30 10:30:21'
GROUP BY organization.name
HAVING count(organization.name) > 1;
```